# What will be the equation of an annulus?

Tags: systems-of-equations, coordinate-systems

Let us consider a circle with radius 4 and a concentric circle with a radius 2. Now if the annular region is shaded, what will be the equation of the shaded annular region?

Comment: $|\sqrt{x^2+y^2}-2|+|\sqrt{x^2+y^2}-4| = 2$

Comment: How is the equation acquired?

Comment: Given any two real numbers $a < b$. another number $x$ lies between $a,b$ (i.e $a \le x \le b$) if only if $|x-a| + |x-b| = |a-b|$. The equation above is a way to express the inequality $2 \le r \le 4$ as an absolute value equation.

Comment: @achillehui That gives the boundary of the annulus, not the shaded annulus.

Comment: @kccu Nope, it do give the area. For example, let's say a point has $r = 3$, then $|r-2| + |r-4| = 1 + 1 = 2$.

Comment: @achillehui I see, my apologies. Any reason your solution is a comment and not an answer?

Comment: @kccu No particular reason. I prefer to leave very short "answer" as comment and if I write an answer, I'll typically put in more details.

Answer (score 1):

$$(x^2+y^2-4)(x^2+y^2-16)\le0.$$

Answer (score 0):

A circle with radius $r$ centered at $(a,b)$ has the equation
$$(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2=r^2$$
(which is seen by using the Pythagorean theorem to calculate the distance between an arbitrary point $(x,y)$ on the circle and the center $(a,b)$).

Every point inside the shaded annulus is on a circle of radius $r$ for some $2 \leq r \leq 4$. Thus, the equation of the shaded annulus is give by:
$$2^2 \leq (x-a)^2+(y-b)^2 \leq 4^4.$$